# How to make datatables and popup work together?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, popup, datatables

This is my header code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>BLOG</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link href="{{ asset ('/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- Drop Down -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <!-- Pop Up -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        @if(Auth::check())
            @include('includes.loggedHeader')
        @else
            @include('includes.header')
        @endif

        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        <!-- Page Heading -->
        @yield('content')
        <!-- /.row --> 
    </body>
    <!-- Drop Down -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Data Table -->
    <script src="{{ asset ('/js/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset ('/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js')}}"></script>
    <!-- Pop Up -->
    <script src="{{ asset ('/js/popup/jquery-1.10.2.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset ('/js/popup/jquery-ui.min.js')}}"></script>

@yield('scripts')
</html>
```

The problem is the datatables and popup can't work together. The datatables will not work if I put the pop up script bellow the datatables script, and the pop up also like that, can't work if the datatables script I put bellow the datatables script. So they can't work together. How to fix it? help me guys. Thanks.

Comment: You seem to have 2 different versions of jquery? One local and one from google?

Comment: ya i have two jquery, local and from google

Comment: That can cause errors. Try using just one and see what happens